# To set html content using html.innerHTML,so that it works in IE 8 and 9

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, dojo, internet-explorer-9

```
var body = dojo.create("html", {innerHTML: tmplStr}).children[1];
```

tmplStr is giving the needed html content. I want to set  it to html.innerHTML. Above code works fine in FireFox,GoogleChrome and IE10. But not working in IE8 and 9.Since innerHTML is read only in IE8 and 9, I'm not able to set the content in IE8 and 9. Please it would great if someone helps me in fixing this issue.

Comment: Just wondering, why would you create a `<html>` element in JavaScript?

Comment: You could juste do something like `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = tmplStr;` ?

Comment: Agreed with g00glen00b, this approach seems very strange.  Maybe if you described the goal of doing this, we can suggest something better.

Comment: Since I dont have dom  element to store the body content...I have created the html.I'm dynamically creating popup.

Answer (score 0):

```
var body = dojo.create("html");
html.set(body, tmplStr).children[1];
```

the above 2 lines will resolve the isssue. It works absolutely fine IE8,9,10, Google chrome and ff

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using jQuery? 
Doing:
  *$('your_selector').text(yourHTMLCode);*

Comment: He didn't ask for jQuery

Comment: thank you dbonfill, but unfortunately jquery is not supported by my application.It would good if I get any solution using dojo or pure javascript.